# John Resig's microtemplating framework throws errors on asp.net web page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, templates, iis

I'm looking into [John Resig's microtemplating framework](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) and it is wonderful, small and fits my requirements. The only problem is that the syntax confuses the ASP.NET framework.  This is due to the fact that anything put inside the

```
<%=id%>
<%=(i % 2 == 1 ? " even" : "")%>
```

expression syntax is evaluated using Server variables. Has anyone hacked/changed the code to work with ASP.NET?

Comment: What exactly is it that doesn't work?  I don't see any obvious problem with that, and most server-side frameworks have similar mechanisms.

Comment: @Pointy have you ever used Asp.net expressions before. From your comment above it seems you haven't :(

Comment: Also, that's an old old blog post, and the template framework is much more evolved than in that post (I think). You should check the [github page](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl) for the project.

Comment: @Pointy the base template i referred to was Standalone wasn't it?

Comment: @Pointy - The problem is probably that the Resig framework wants to interpret those tags with client-side JavaScript, but ASP.NET interprets them as server tags.

Comment: @Pointy jQuery template and john resigs micro templating system are two different (independant) things

Comment: ... what do you mean by "base template"?  I'm confused. If you're talking about that template code in the blog post, then yes that's a standalone "library", but my point was that it's just some code from a blog post. If you want something more full-featured and adaptable, you may want to check out the jQuery version.

Comment: @Pointy i certainly agree with you on that point `If you want something more full-featured and adaptable,`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just change `<%` and `%>` in the parsing function to `<#` and `#>`, respectively. I've seen it done, and it works great.

```
 // Convert the template into pure JavaScript
    str
      .replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
      .split("<#").join("\t")
      .replace(/((^|\#>)[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r")   //note the extra \ here
      .replace(/\t=(.*?)\#>/g, "',$1,'")      //and here
      .split("\t").join("');")
      .split("#>").join("p.push('")
      .split("\r").join("\\'")
```

...etc.

Comment: If it helps I've also seen <% changed to {%

Answer (score 2):

If it's not working because of `<%` and `%>`, then you can easily change the source code.

```
    str
      .replace(/[\r\t\n]/g, " ")
      .split("<%").join("\t") // this % you could change to @ or whatever
      .replace(/((^|%>)[^\t]*)'/g, "$1\r") // same here
      .replace(/\t=(.*?)%>/g, "',$1,'") // same here
      .split("\t").join("');")
      .split("%>").join("p.push('") // same here
      .split("\r").join("\\'")
```

Comment: i did change 'line 3' to `<@` and 'line 7' to `@>` in the above posted code and it threw me a error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =` it is more than replacing string

Answer (score 2):

Rick Strahl had a good post a while back where he modified it to be ASP.NET friendly (the microtemplating is toward the end; scroll down): http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2008/Oct/13/Client-Templating-with-jQuery

Answer (score 1):

You could also replace the % sign with the unicode representation of the percentage sign in JavaScript strings which is '\u0025'. So instead of the string "<%=id%>" you'd write "<\u0025=id\u0025>"